# Grouped ComboBox causes InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, xaml

I'd like to display a ComboBox with groups. As soon as the page gets rendered I get an InvalidCastException with the following message (no stack trace)

> Schnittstelle nicht unterstützt

Translation would be something like

> Interface not supported

I guess it's some XAML thing since my code is working well when the `<ComboBox.GroupStyle>` part is removed. What's going wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="TileOptions" IsSourceGrouped="True" Source="{Binding LiveTileTypeOptions}" />
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TileOptions}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <CarouselPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ComboBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, LiveTileTypeDescription>> LiveTileTypeOptions
{
    get { return TileFactory.GetTileTypeOptions().GroupBy(t => t.Category).OrderBy(g => g.Key); }
}
```

`LiveTileTypeDescription` is a simple class with few prperties. `Category` is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/705cbba2-1322-4822-af49-191c741d7b19/grouping-in-a-combobox-not-possible?forum=winappswithcsharp) grouping in a ComboBox is not possible. The thread is from 2012 but i guess it still applies.

Comment: I found an other solution for my problem in the meantime. Anyway thanks for your answer!